# C# where inside a where in Templates / Generics

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I am working with templates. In my method there is a Template (TBase) which is dependent on another Template (TChild) and both TBase and TChild derives from different classes.

Here is the code.

```
public void SomeMethod<TBase>()
    where TBase : class, ISomeInterface<TChild>, new()
    where TChild : IAnotherInterface   // Problem is here.
```

I need to tell method TChild is implementing IAnotherInterface or derving from a class. But compiler gives me error as TChild type or namespace could not be found.

Where should I put my second `where`

Comment: Does `public void SomeMethod<TBase, TChild>()` work for you?

Comment: Can you post your class declaration please?

Comment: It will work, but I will have to change all the calls to this method, so that is not a good option for me,

Comment: public SomeClass<TBase, TChild>

Answer (score 1):

You can just have:

```
public void SomeMethod<TBase>()
where TBase : class, ISomeInterface<IAnotherInterface>, new()
{

}
```

**Iff**, we have the following definitions:

```
class Base : ISomeInterface<Child>{}
class Child : IAnotherInterface{}
interface ISomeInterface<out T>{}
interface IAnotherInterface{}
```

Specifically, `ISomeInterface` has to be [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) in its generic type parameter.

Otherwise, as others are pointing out, if you want to express any type constraint, you need to have (the type to be constrained) as a type parameter on your method.

Answer (score 0):

This will compile:

```
public void SomeMethod<TBase, TChild>()
    where TBase : class, ISomeInterface<TChild>, new()
    where TChild : IAnotherInterface // No problem is here. 
{
}

internal interface IAnotherInterface
{
}

internal interface ISomeInterface<TChild>
{
}
```